# Javascript show/hide div onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I have a page that contains three divs each div is a paragraph. I want to use javascript to show each div only in the page whenever the user presses on it from the navbar
[This is the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LnsS.png)

WebDev is only one page that consist of three different divs as shown here

```
<!--HTML-->
<div class="html" id="html-show">
    <p class="text-html" id="htmlContent">..
    </p>
</div>

<!--CSS-->
<div class="css" id="css-show">
    <p class="text-css" id="cssContent">..
    </p>
</div>

<!--JS-->
<div class="js" id="js-show">
    <p class="text-js" id="jsContent">..
    </p>
</div>
```

So, if the user presses on HTML in the navbar he will be redirected to this page and only HTML div is visible, same goes for css and js. In fact, other parts of the page will be shown (navbar, footer, etc..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont even need JS for it. You can do it solely with HTML and CSS with the use of anchors and `:target` like in the snippet below.

```css
#html-show, #css-show, #js-show {
  display: none;
}

#html-show:target, #css-show:target, #js-show:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--Nav-Bar-->
<a href="#html-show">Show HTML</a>
<a href="#css-show">Show CSS</a>
<a href="#js-show">Show JS</a>

<!--HTML-->
<div class="html" id="html-show">
    <p class="text-html" id="htmlContent">HTML Content..
    </p>
</div>

<!--CSS-->
<div class="css" id="css-show">
    <p class="text-css" id="cssContent">CSS Content..
    </p>
</div>

<!--JS-->
<div class="js" id="js-show">
    <p class="text-js" id="jsContent">JS Content..
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What if first content `HTML Content..` needs to be visible initially?

Comment: then either redirect directly to that link (.htaccess) or link to the anchor.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function showHtmlDiv() {
  var htmlShow = document.getElementById("html-show");
  if (htmlShow.style.display === "none") {
    htmlShow.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    htmlShow.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showHtmlDiv()">Click Here</button>
<div id="html-show">
  <p class="text-html" id="htmlContent">..
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it (changing the visibiltiy css property of a specific element in plain javascript).

```
// You would change the id to the id of the button element (so the links in your navbar)
var button = document.getElementById('button');
// This is the element that you either want to be hidden or shown
var elementToBeToggled = document.getElementById('elementToBeToggled');
// states whether or not the element is visible in this current state.
var elementVisible = "hidden";

// This function will be run when you click the link in the navbar
function toggleElement() {
  // Ternary operation that basically changes elementVisible to its opposite
  elementVisible = elementVisible === "hidden" ? elementVisible = "visible" : elementVisible = "hidden";

  // change element visiblity to elementVisible variable
  elementToBeToggled.style.visiblity = elementVisible;
}

// Run toggle function on button click
button.onclick = toggleElement;
```

This solution is a lot more flexible than if you were to just put an `onclick` event inside of a `<button>` tag as you can only but the `onclick` event in that single html tag and it would not work if lets say the toggle button was an `<a>` tag. It is a lot easier to style `<a>` tags to make navbars to I am assuming this solution would be viable to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a css approach.  When loading your page, add some unique identifier class to the body of the document, and based on that determine the visibility of different parts.  Also, add the query param to your link(s).  Now if you load the page with index.html?show=html, only the html div will be visible.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       //this is just for illustration purposes, use a parser library
       function getParams () {
          return document.location.search.substr(1).split("&").reduce(function (acc, p) {
             const [key, value] = p.split("=");
             if (typeof(value) !== "undefined") {
                 acc[key] = value;
             }
             return acc;
          }, {});
       }

       document.addEventListener("load", function () {
          const params = getParams();
          body.classList.add("show-" + (params.show || "all"));
       });
    </script>
    <style>
      .html, .css, .js {
         display: none;
      }
      body.show-all .html, body.show-all .css, body.show-all .js {
         display: block;
      }
      body.show-html .html {
         display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     ...
  </body>
</html>
```