# How do I set an onClick event on my <h2> tag which when clicked will show the subsequent list items?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to Web development. I am working on registering an onClick event to my **h2** element, which when clicked will show the below list of data. If clicked anywhere, it should hide the list. My html code is as following:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <title>New page</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <script src="frontend.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h1>Hello</h1>

      
        <h2>Disclaimer</h2>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <nav>
             <ol>
               <li>ABCDEF<br></li>
               <li>GHIJKL<br></li>
               <li>MNOPQRST<br></li>
            
             </ol>
          </nav>
        </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

When the text **Disclaimer** is pressed once, only then it should show the list. When pressed again, it should be hidden. How do I do this?

Comment: you can do something like this [js onclick hide/show answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64487640/javascript-show-hide-div-onclick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add onClick event to  your Disclaimer H2.
2. Next, set display:none for
   your list on load, which will get  toggled to block when click.
3. Finally,  define the function to handle onClick event.

Demo: https://jsbin.com/cazamiwifu/edit?html,output

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
       <head>
          <title>New page</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
          <script src="frontend.js"></script>
       </head>
    
       <body>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
    
          
            <h2 onclick="toggle()">Disclaimer</h2>
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDIV" style="display:none;">
              <nav>
                 <ol>
                   <li>ABCDEF<br></li>
                   <li>GHIJKL<br></li>
                   <li>MNOPQRST<br></li>
                
                 </ol>
              </nav>
            </div>
    <script>
      function toggle() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's strange, I have written the code in my `frontend.js` file, and it's not working.

Comment: OK, my bad, I accidentally named my file as `frontend,js` instead of `frontend.js`. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

like that :

```js
<script>
    document.onclick= function(event) {
      if(event.target == document.getElementById("target")){
          if(document.getElementById("nav").style.display == "block"){
              document.getElementById("nav").style.display ="none";
          }else {
              document.getElementById("nav").style.display ="block";
          }

      }else{
          document.getElementById("nav").style.display ="none";
        }
    }
</script>
```