# How to hide or show the desired block when clicking on an element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a list-menu .sidebar-menu and each li of this list has its own id. There is also a .services-info block, where blocks are located, one of which should appear when you click on one of the items in the .sidebar-menu that corresponds to this block. On the blocks in .services-info, I hung the .invisible class, which hides them and there is a .visible class with the display: block property.
Question: How to make it so that when you click on one of the .sidebar-menu items, the corresponding block appears and the unnecessary one disappears? For example, I clicked on the "Business card site" item and in .services-info (circled in red in the picture) the corresponding block appears (with the .business-card class) and the previous block disappears, or I clicked on the "Online store" item and it appears also the corresponding block (with class .market). and unnecessary disappears.

Site ct03638.tmweb.ru

Code jsfiddle.net/qhfs7jmb/

[image]

```css
.invisible{
    display:  none;
}


.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="services" id="services">
            <div class="services-info-bg"></div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="sidebar">
                        <h3>Наши услуги</h3>
                        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                            <li id="business-card"><a href="#">Сайт-визитка</a></li>
                            <li id="landing"><a href="#">Landing page</a></li>
                            <li id="market"><a href="#">Интернет-магазин</a></li>
                            <li id="corp"><a href="#">Корпоративный сайт</a></li>
                            <li id="bitrix"><a href="#">1C Битрикс</a></li>
                            <li id="advertising"><a href="#">Контекстная реклама</a></li>
                            <li id="seo"><a href="#">SEO оптимизация</a></li>
                            <li id="promotion"><a href="#">Продвижение в соц. сетях</a></li>
                            <li id="marketing"><a href="#">Контент-маркетинг</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="services-info">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="business-card invisible">Сайт-визитка</div>
                            <div class="landin invisible">Landing page</div>
                            <div class="market">
                                <div class="services-info-title">
                                    Созданные экспертами «Inter-web» сайты интернет-магазинов имеют функциональность, необходимую для успешной онлайн-торговли.
                                </div>
                                <p>Что входит в нашу работу:</p>
                                <div class="services-info-block">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>+ Подготовка технического задания</li>
                                        <li>+ Разработка прототипа</li>
                                        <li>+ Верстка макета</li>
                                        <li>+ Интеграция дизайна</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>+ Написание уникальных текстов</li>
                                        <li>+ Сбор семантики</li>
                                        <li>+ Тестирование и запуск</li>
                                        <li>+ Подключение веб-аналитики</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="services-info-footer">
                                    <a class="order" href="#">Сделать заказ</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="details">Узнать подробнее &rarr;</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: It seems that you left out your JavaScript. Does this answer your question? [Javascript show/hide div onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64487640/javascript-show-hide-div-onclick)

Comment: this is a good solution, but for some reason it does not work for me and I also need the first element to be displayed, and they are all hidden here, and if you put display: block, then it will not disappear when other blocks are active

Comment: Not sure what you mean, since there are several different solutions in that post. However, you could edit your question and show us what you tried and what specifically goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the sidebar `<ul>` to listen for clicks on the sidebar elements.

When the user clicks on a sidebar element the event listener looks for the ID of the clicked element and uses that to construct a query selector to select the required content `<div>`.

Then add the `invisible` class and remove the 'visible' class on all the content `<div>`, and finally set the 'visible' class on the required content `<div>`

You could just search for the `visible` content block and change that, but past experience has taught me to hide everything I don't want, regardless.

The code you need shoud be enclosed within `<script>` tags and added to the foot of your page.

```js
    document.querySelector('ul.sidebar-menu').addEventListener('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // The <a> element was clicked, but we need the ID from the enclosing <li> element
        let clickedId = e.target.closest('li').id;
        // Set all the content elements to invisible (saves trying to find the visible one)
        let contentDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div.services-info>div.content>div');
        contentDivs.forEach((el)=>{el.classList.remove('visible'); el.classList.add('invisible')});
        // Now, using the ID from the <li>, create a query selector to find the content <div>
        let targetSelector = 'div.services-info>div.content>div.'+clickedId;
        // Set that element visible
        document.querySelector(targetSelector).classList.add('visible');
    });
```

```css
.invisible{
    display:  none;
}


.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="services" id="services">
            <div class="services-info-bg"></div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="sidebar">
                        <h3>Наши услуги</h3>
                        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                            <li id="business-card"><a href="#">Сайт-визитка</a></li>
                            <li id="landing"><a href="#">Landing page</a></li>
                            <li id="market"><a href="#">Интернет-магазин</a></li>
                            <li id="corp"><a href="#">Корпоративный сайт</a></li>
                            <li id="bitrix"><a href="#">1C Битрикс</a></li>
                            <li id="advertising"><a href="#">Контекстная реклама</a></li>
                            <li id="seo"><a href="#">SEO оптимизация</a></li>
                            <li id="promotion"><a href="#">Продвижение в соц. сетях</a></li>
                            <li id="marketing"><a href="#">Контент-маркетинг</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="services-info">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="business-card invisible">Сайт-визитка</div>
                            <div class="landing invisible">Landing page</div>
                            <div class="market">
                                <div class="services-info-title">
                                    Созданные экспертами «Inter-web» сайты интернет-магазинов имеют функциональность, необходимую для успешной онлайн-торговли.
                                </div>
                                <p>Что входит в нашу работу:</p>
                                <div class="services-info-block">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>+ Подготовка технического задания</li>
                                        <li>+ Разработка прототипа</li>
                                        <li>+ Верстка макета</li>
                                        <li>+ Интеграция дизайна</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>+ Написание уникальных текстов</li>
                                        <li>+ Сбор семантики</li>
                                        <li>+ Тестирование и запуск</li>
                                        <li>+ Подключение веб-аналитики</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="services-info-footer">
                                    <a class="order" href="#">Сделать заказ</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="details">Узнать подробнее &rarr;</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Did I understand the logic of the code correctly?

1) Add an event listener to ul.sidebar-menu to listen for clicks on list items.
2) In the variable clickedId, enclose the id of the parent of the clicked element
3) in the variable contentDivs we wrap all the blocks in .services-info .content

Comment: 4) for contentDivs, the forEach method is launched, where, iterating over each element, it removes the visible class and adds invisible
 5) targetSelector = 'div.servicesinfo> div.content> div.' + ClickedId. Here I do not understand what is written. Is there a search for a match of the block class name inside .services-info .content with the identifier of the pressed "li" in .sidebar-menu and if they match, then the block becomes visible?

Comment: @Outif You have it right, and  you have understood the logic at 5) correctly. The query selectors are more involved than they might be because you've used classes almost everywhere, so the selectors have to be very specific on class.  The format of the selector searches for children rather than descendant. This is a more specific search. If the classes `business-card`, `landing`, `market` etc. are used only once on the page then you could just search for them directly.

Comment: Another question - why does the code stop working if 'e' is removed in function (e) and e.preventDefault () is removed inside the function?

Comment: So I understood correctly that in the variable targetSelector compares the id of the pressed li and the class inside the .content block? And if they are similar in name, then the desired block becomes visible?

Comment: `e` is the event object. Because the listener is added to the `ul` element it requires this to identify which link is clicked. The actual clicked element is an `<a>`. `preventDefault()` tells the browser not to redirect to the link. Without it the browser would simply reload the page and the code wouldn't be executed. See the [MDN Event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Comment: ok, you can also explain what's going on in the targetSelector = 'div.services-info> div.content> div.' + clickedId?

Comment: Why is the comparison so unusual? Usually the comparison is something like e.target === ...

Comment: It's not a comparison. It's a concatenation to produce a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 0):

One method is to set an attribute with selected menu item id on `body` element and in CSS show the element with the same class name.
The section that you want to show when clicked menu item must have the same class name as the id of `<li>` item:

```js
const menu = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar-menu li > a"),
      onClick = e =>
      {
        e.preventDefault();
        //get ID from <li> element and add to the body "show" attribute
        document.body.setAttribute("show", e.target.parentNode.id);
      };

for(let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++)
  menu[i].addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

```css
.services-info .content > div
{
  display: none;
}

body[show="business-card"] .business-card,
body[show="landing"] .landing,
body[show="market"] .market,
body[show="corp"] .corp,
body[show="bitrix"] .bitrix,
body[show="advertising"] .advertising,
body[show="seo"] .seo,
body[show="promotion"] .promotion,
body[show="marketing"] .marketing
{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="services" id="services">
            <div class="services-info-bg"></div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="sidebar">
                        <h3>Наши услуги</h3>
                        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                            <li id="business-card"><a href="#">Сайт-визитка</a></li>
                            <li id="landing"><a href="#">Landing page</a></li>
                            <li id="market"><a href="#">Интернет-магазин</a></li>
                            <li id="corp"><a href="#">Корпоративный сайт</a></li>
                            <li id="bitrix"><a href="#">1C Битрикс</a></li>
                            <li id="advertising"><a href="#">Контекстная реклама</a></li>
                            <li id="seo"><a href="#">SEO оптимизация</a></li>
                            <li id="promotion"><a href="#">Продвижение в соц. сетях</a></li>
                            <li id="marketing"><a href="#">Контент-маркетинг</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="services-info">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="business-card invisible">Сайт-визитка</div>
                            <div class="landing invisible">Landing page</div>
                            <div class="market">
                                <div class="services-info-title">
                                    Созданные экспертами «Inter-web» сайты интернет-магазинов имеют функциональность, необходимую для успешной онлайн-торговли.
                                </div>
                                <p>Что входит в нашу работу:</p>
                                <div class="services-info-block">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>+ Подготовка технического задания</li>
                                        <li>+ Разработка прототипа</li>
                                        <li>+ Верстка макета</li>
                                        <li>+ Интеграция дизайна</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>+ Написание уникальных текстов</li>
                                        <li>+ Сбор семантики</li>
                                        <li>+ Тестирование и запуск</li>
                                        <li>+ Подключение веб-аналитики</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="services-info-footer">
                                    <a class="order" href="#">Сделать заказ</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="details">Узнать подробнее &rarr;</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Did I understand the logic of the code correctly?      
   
1) in the const variable we add all the links that are inside the .sidebar-menu li
2) when you click on one of the 'li', an event occurs
3) using document.body.setAttribute ("show", e.target.parentNode.id) add the attribute "show", which is written in advance body [show = "business-card"] .business-card,
body [show = "landing"] .landing etc., where the value of "show" is the id of the pressed li in the .sidebar-menu li, right? That is, body [show = "id of the pressed element li"] .business-card.

Comment: 4) Using e.target.parentNode.id we get the id of the clicked .sidebar-menu li, namely: e.target is a link to the object that was clicked, parentNode.id returns the id of the parent of the element that was clicked. Tying it all together
it turns out that when I click on the link, I get the id of the li that I clicked on, right? Since the link is inside li.
5) I run the "for" loop inside which every link inside the .sidebar-menu li is checked if there is a click.

Questions: Is it possible to get the id of the pressed .sidebar-menu li via document.getElementById ()?

Comment: Yes, you dissected it pretty well, except for 5) - it doesn't check for clicks, it register a click event listener, which fires when the link is clicked. Technically with this method you don't really need the `<a>` links inside `<li>` you can add event listeners in 5) directly on `<li>` elements and get rid off `<a>`. I left them there in case you have some specific style for them. I'm not quiet understand the last question...since `li` elements have id attribute, you can use `document.getElementById()` to retrieve each of them individually.